# GUID field error when trying to Create a Local Copy

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-online, arcgis-10.3, relationship-class

I am hosting our tree inventory data ArcGIS Online so that our Urban Forester can do tree inspections and create work recommendations to field maintenance staff. The database consists of multiple related tables, related by Global ID and GUID fields.

Once the edits have been made in esri's Collector App, I need to being them back into ArcMap (10.3). I am able to do this just fine, but when I try to "Create Local Copy for Editing" I get the following error:

[image: A local copy could not be created. A general error when something is wrong with a Field. REC_ID The operation was attempted on an empty geometry.]

REC_ID refers to the GUID field for my Work_Recommendations feature class.

I need to be able to sync my local copy edits back to the hosted feature service, so that I don't have to re-publish the feature service.

The reason for using the Global_ID as the primary key and GUID as the foreign key relationship classes is that I need to generate the unique TREE_IDs on the back end, and Collector app does not support Object ID relationships. There are two feature classes and five related tables. I updated the Geometry for the Work_Recommendations feature class (REC_ID), but I cannot do the same for the tables, of which most have GUID fields.

I attempted to export the feature layer to a FGDB, as was suggested in a comment, and this wasn't able to be accomplished either. I received another error (this time, less specific): 
[image: Error exporting data to filegdb format]

Can anyone help me identify the issue with my database?

Comment: Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to include additional information like the above.  Comments can be considered temporary and potential answerers do not always read them.

Comment: Simply export service to FGDB from AGOL

Comment: @GISjaclyn I'd suggest contacting ESRI tech support for this if you haven't already

Comment: Has anyone tried it with a feature service hosted locally? The bug says it is with hosted feature services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug ([BUG-000089105](http://support.esri.com/en/bugs/nimbus/QlVHLTAwMDA4OTEwNQ==)). When Guid field exists in your data, ArcMap is unable to make a local copy of feature service. One way to work around it is to use ArcGIS Pro and to edit the service directly.